# LateInitializationError: Field '_deviceLocale@66168148' has not been initialized when use easy_localization to international the flutter app

Tags: flutter

I am using `easy_localization` to localization the flutter app(flutter stable 2.5.3), but when I run the app, shows error like this:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following LateError was thrown attaching to the render tree:
LateInitializationError: Field '_deviceLocale@66168148' has not been initialized.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      EasyLocalizationController._deviceLocale (package:easy_localization/src/easy_localization_controller.dart)
#1      new EasyLocalizationController.<anonymous closure> (package:easy_localization/src/easy_localization_controller.dart:52:48)
#2      ListMixin.firstWhere (dart:collection/list.dart:161:15)
#3      new EasyLocalizationController (package:easy_localization/src/easy_localization_controller.dart:51:34)
#4      _EasyLocalizationState.initState (package:easy_localization/src/easy_localization_app.dart:120:30)
#5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:57)
#6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4638:5)
#7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3673:14)
#8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3425:18)
#9      RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1198:16)
#10     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1167:5)
#11     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1112:18)
#12     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2573:19)
#13     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:13)
#14     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:944:7)
#15     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:924:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================
```

To reproduce the problem, I made a minimal example. this is the `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization_loader/easy_localization_loader.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_learn/utilities/language_util.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(EasyLocalization(
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale(kLanguageEN),
          Locale(kLanguageZH),
        ],
        path: 'assets/translations',
        assetLoader: YamlAssetLoader(),
        fallbackLocale: Locale(kLanguageEN),
        child: Container(),
      ));
    }
```

and this is the `language_util.dart` file:

```
import 'package:easy_localization/src/public_ext.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_learn/utilities/r.dart';


const kLanguageDE = 'de';
const kLanguageEN = 'en';
const kLanguageES = 'es';
const kLanguageFR = 'fr';
const kLanguageIT = 'it';
const kLanguageJA = 'ja';
const kLanguageKO = 'ko';
const kLanguagePT = 'pt';
const kLanguageRU = 'ru';
const kLanguageZH = 'zh';

final List<String> kAppLanguages = [
  kLanguageEN,
  kLanguageZH,
];

final List<String> kSupportedLanguages = [
  kLanguageDE,
  kLanguageEN,
  kLanguageES,
  kLanguageFR,
  kLanguageIT,
  kLanguageJA,
  kLanguageKO,
  kLanguagePT,
  kLanguageRU,
  kLanguageZH,
];

final Map<String, String> _knownFlagIcons = {
  kLanguageDE: 'de',
  kLanguageEN: 'gb',
  kLanguageES: 'es',
  kLanguageFR: 'fr',
  kLanguageIT: 'in',
  kLanguageJA: 'jp',
  kLanguageKO: 'kr',
  kLanguagePT: 'pt',
  kLanguageRU: 'ru',
  kLanguageZH: 'cn',
};

String getLanguageName(String language) {
  return 'language.$language'.tr();
}

String getLanguageFlag(String language) {
  return R.image('flag_icons/${_knownFlagIcons[language]}.svg');
}

Locale languageToLocale(String language) {
  if (language.contains('-')) {
    return Locale(
        language.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(), language.substring(1));
  }
  return Locale(language);
}
```

this is the `r.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class R {
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey;

  static setNavigatorKey(GlobalKey navigatorKey) {
    _navigatorKey = navigatorKey;
  }

  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> getNavigatorKey() {
    return _navigatorKey;
  }

  static String image(String name) {
    return 'assets/images/$name';
  }
}
```

and this is the yaml define:

```
name: flutter_learn
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  easy_localization_loader: ^1.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/translations/
```

am I missing something? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You forgot initialize easy_localization ([official example](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization/example)). You need to call

```dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
```

before creating your `EasyLocalization` widget.
The `WidgetsFlutterBinding` is, according to the docs

```
A concrete binding for applications based on the Widgets framework.

This is the glue that binds the framework to the Flutter engine.
```

That is needed to, for example, get the device locale, which is done by the `EasyLocalization` initialization.

Comment: Replace also void main() { by Future<void> main() async { !